# MySQL one query executed on two identical servers uses different indexes

Tags: mysql

I have two identical databases on separate server machines, and if I execute one query on both machines, on one server it would go smoothly while on the other it would cause slow log. Explain shows me that they are not using same indexes. Any suggestion or advice, it would be helpful.

Comment: Migrate this to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The index statistics which MySQL keeps, sometimes become inaccurate (I don't know why/when).

Running `ANALYZE TABLE <table>` on both servers should correct the statistics.

If the problem appears again, you can use index hints and/or `IF`'s to force MySQL to use the correct index.